# Configure the httpErrors element to display a generic error page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I configure the `httpErrors` element in the web.config to display a generic Error page based on a specific HTTP error that was thrown?

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 4` and `.NET 4.5`.

I have the following files in the root of my web application:

```
403.html
404.html
500.html
```

I have the following setup in my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
     <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
     <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
          <remove statusCode="403" />
          <remove statusCode="404" />
          <remove statusCode="500" />
          <error statusCode="403" path="403.html" responseMode="File" />
          <error statusCode="404" path="404.html" responseMode="File" />
          <error statusCode="500" path="500.html" responseMode="File" />
     </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

I tested the above by doing something like this:

```
throw new System.Web.HttpException(403, "403");
```

This works perfect for me, the correct HTML file is displayed based on one of the above mentioned HTTP errors.

I would like to move away from the above HTML files and rather display a generic error page found in my `Views/Shared` folder. It is called `Error.cshtml`. I'm not sure how to change the above to display this new error page?

I have set `existingResponse` to `Auto`, `Replace` and `PassThrough` but it just displays a white page. I've changed `path` to a couple of variations like `path="/Error"` and `path="Views/Shared/Error"` and this also doesn't work.

Comment: did you try to create an errorcontroller/action, that returns error view and change path to that action?

Comment: Yes I do but I need it this way so that I can cater for IIS errors as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a controller for this. Your action can be as simple as

```
public ActionResult Error()
{
    return View("~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml");
}
```

But you still need it if you want to use ASP.NET MVC mechanism for error page display.

After you defined the controller with action above (lets say controller name is Error as well), you can compose url just like to any other ASP.NET MVC page: `Error/Error`.

**Update.** Here is an example config:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom"
            defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL"
            defaultPath="/Error/Error>
</httpErrors>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Can you show me what you httpErrors would look like then?

Comment: Default with a web app there is a file in Views/Shared called Error.cshtml. I would like to use that. Is this possible?

Comment: @BrendanVogt, of course. This is the matter of the action what view you are going to display. Updated the answer to clarify this. Note that `defaultPath` in config is not a path - its an URL that will be called

Comment: So it has to go through a controller? Just wondering because the .HTML error files that I had doesn't need a controller, it was just picked up based on the settings in httpErrors.

Comment: Yes but that is the Error view for the Error controller. How do I specify it to use the `Error.cshtml` file in `Views/Shared`? This can be done in `httpErrors`? If so can you please add it to your answer?

Comment: @BrendanVogt, that was when you were using plain html pages. Now you want to use ASP.NET MVC view. Of course it should go through the whole pipeline to be shown correctly. As for the view in error controller - note that the exact path is specified in the code. It does not necessary have to be Error folder, Shared can be used as well (that is what Shared folder is for actually).

Answer (score 0):

**You can catch all the errors in Global.asax**

```
 protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var httpContext = ((MvcApplication)sender).Context;
            var currentRouteData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));
            var currentController = " ";
            var currentAction = " ";
            if (currentRouteData != null)
            {
                if (currentRouteData.Values["controller"] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()))
                {
                    currentController = currentRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
                }

                if (currentRouteData.Values["action"] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRouteData.Values["action"].ToString()))
                {
                    currentAction = currentRouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
                }
            }
            var ex = Server.GetLastError();
            var url = Request.RawUrl;
            var controller = new ErrorController();
            var routeData = new RouteData();
            var action = "Error";
            httpContext.ClearError();
            httpContext.Response.Clear();
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = ex is HttpException ? ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode() : 500;
            httpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
            routeData.Values["action"] = action;
            controller.ViewData.Model = new NameSpace.HandleErrorInfo(ex, currentController, currentAction);
            ((IController)controller).Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext), routeData));
        }
```

**Before that create an Model, for stroing error information:**

```
public class HandleErrorInfo
    {
        public string ActionName { get; set; }
        public string ControllerName { get; set; }
        public Exception Exception { get; set; }
        public HandleErrorInfo(Exception exception, string controllerName,
            string actionName)
        {
            this.ActionName = actionName;
            this.ControllerName = controllerName;
            this.Exception = exception;
        }
    }
```

**Error View:** Stongly binded with Above error model. This displays all errors:

```
@model NameSpace.HandleErrorInfo
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Error Page</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("../../Content/site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("../../Content/css/menu.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
           <div class="container">
            <div>
                <table id="tblError" visible="false" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width="90%"
                    border="0" style="margin-left: 50px">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" class="pageTitle">
                            Application Error
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-family: Arial; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt; text-align: center">
                            <br />
                            We are sorry, but an unhandled error occured on the server. The server administrator
                            has been notified and error logged. Please find error details below:
                            <br />
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="40%" align="center">
                            <div id="ErrorInfo">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="tdCol1Align">
                                            <b>Controller Name :</b>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="tdCol2Align">
                                            <b>@Model.ControllerName</b>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="tdCol1Align">
                                            <b>Action Name:</b>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="tdCol2Align">
                                            <b>@Model.ActionName</b>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <b>Error Description:</b><br />
                                <br />
                                <p>
                                    @Model.Exception</p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>
               xyz            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller for Error View:**

```
 public class ErrorController : Controller
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Action Method for Rendering Error View upon Error Occurance
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public ActionResult Error()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I do have something similar like this, but I need it to capture IIS errors as well.

Comment: @BrendanVogt..IIS errors..any sample error? It captures all the errors